# How to convert set to float or integer

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, set, nltk

I am interested in plotting the unique values in an integer vector u against the number of times each of those unique values occurs in u, (i.e. the frequency distribution of unique values occurring in u).

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer,word_tokenize
from nltk import FreqDist
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

txtwrds=state_union.words('2006-GWBush.txt')
vocab=set(w.lower() for w in txtwrds if w.isalpha())
vocab=nltk.Text(vocab)
fdist1=FreqDist(txtwrds)
u=[]
for w in vocab:
    u.append(fdist1[w])

x=FreqDist(u)
y=set(u)
print(len(x),len(y))  #Gives same vector length for x and y
plt.scatter(x,y)  #This is what throws the error
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the last few lines of code, in order to get a new vector y of the unique values in u I run "y=set(u)."  And I assign "x=FreqDist(u)."  So far so good.  Problem comes when I try to plot x and y using matplotlib's "scatter."  I get "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'"

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/first_program.py", line 45, in <module>
plt.scatter(x,y)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3200, in scatter
linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3674, in scatter
self.add_collection(collection)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1477, in add_collection
self.update_datalim(collection.get_datalim(self.transData))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 192, in get_datalim
offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, np.float_)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 525, in asanyarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'
```

Attempts at converting y to integer or float (y=int(y),y=float(y)) meet with errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/first_program.py", line 44, in <module>
y=int(y)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

FYI - I am using 32 bit python v3.4.3 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  (There are some nltk bugs arising with 64 bit python v3.5, so have to use the earlier version.)

Comment: `[ float(x) for x in the_set ]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with pandas.DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pds
df = pds.DataFrame(data=[txtwords],columns=['word'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)  #just to have a column to count
df.groupby('word').count().plot()
```